# How do i search a large amount of folders for two kinds of files and compare their sizes?

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have a lot of differently structured folders, i want to search for two file extensions that will exist in the same folder. I need to compare the size of these two files.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\SharedFolders\ -Recurse | ?{$_.Extension -eq ".qbw"}
```

I can get the first item, but i'm not sure how to tell it to compare to a file in the same directory

Should i pass it to another command or try working with arrays?

Comment: I tried an array but due to some path stuff they aren't coming out the same.

Comment: Ultimate goal is to find a .qbw and compare it to the .tlg in the same folder

Comment: Does the .tlg file have the same name as the .qbw file, or is it there only one .tlg file in each folder?

Comment: every QBW and TLG have the same name before the extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `ForEach-Object` loop, e.g like this:

```
$root = 'C:\SharedFolders'
Get-ChildItem -Path $root -Filter '*.qbw' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  $tlg = Get-ChildItem $_.Directory -Filter '*.tlg' | Select -First 1
  if ($tlg) {
    Compare-Object $_ $tlg
  }
}
```

If .tlg and .qbw files have the same basename use something like this:

```
$root = 'C:\SharedFolders'
Get-ChildItem -Path $root -Filter '*.qbw' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  $tlgpath = $_.FullName -replace '\.qbw$', '.tlg'
  If (Test-Path -LiteralPath $tlgpath) {
    $tlg = Get-Item $tlgpath
    Compare-Object $_ $tlg
  }
}
```